# Why the control goes to the else block for this conditional check?

Tags: c, unsigned-integer

I want to know that why it only executes the else statement

The code is Given below:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    unsigned int a = 100;
    int b = -100;
    if(a > b)
    {
        print("Obviously 100 is Bigger than -100!\n");
    }
    else
        print("Something Unexpected has Happened\n");
}
```

Comment: Why the downvote? Apart from the awful formatting, this is well presented and answerable, and truly bewildering the first time you encounter this.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker: My instinct suggested to me that this one had a duplicate and there was also nothing else special in the question to warrant a brand-new answer, which is why I didn't answer. Personally I think that it should be possible to upvote and downvote the actions of a duplicate spotter.

Comment: (note for the record I wasn't the one downvoting - I agree with the sentiment that a downvote wasn't warranted)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because the value -100 is being converted to a large positive value.

What you see is a result of the **usual arithmetic conversions**.  When a signed integer value and an unsigned integer value of the same rank (`int` and `unsigned int` in this case) are used in an expression, the signed value is converted to the unsigned value.

These conversions are spelled out in section 6.3.1.8p1 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> If both operands have the same type, then no further conversion is
>   needed.
>
> Otherwise, if both operands have signed integer types or both have
>   unsigned integer  types,  the  operand  with  the  type  of  lesser 
>   integer  conversion  rank  is converted to the type of the operand
>   with greater rank.
>
> **Otherwise,  if  the  operand  that  has  unsigned  integer  type  has 
>   rank  greater  or equal  to  the  rank  of  the  type  of  the  other 
>   operand,  then  the  operand  with signed  integer  type  is 
>   converted  to  the  type  of  the  operand  with  unsigned integer
>   type.**
>
> Otherwise, if the type of the operand with signed integer type can
>   represent all of the values of the type of the operand with unsigned
>   integer type, then the  operand  with  unsigned  integer  type  is 
>   converted  to  the  type  of  the operand with signed integer type.
>
> Otherwise,   both   operands   are   converted   to   the   unsigned
>   integer   type corresponding to the type of the operand with signed
>   integer type.

The highlighted paragraph is what applies in this case.  As for how the actual conversion occurs, that is spelled out in section 6.3.1.3p2:

> Otherwise,  if  the  new  type  is  unsigned,  the  value  is  converted  by  repeatedly  adding  or subtracting  one  more  than  the  maximum  value  that  can  be  represented  in  the  new type until the value is in the range of the new type.

So assuming an `unsigned int` is 32 bits in size with no padding bytes, the maximum value it can hold is 4294967295.  That means that the value -100 is converted to the value 4294967196.  This means the comparison that is actually performed is `100 > 4294967295` which is false, so the `else` portion of the statement is executed.

Comment: You don't mind my edit, so I can upvote with a clear conscience?

Comment: @Bathsheba No problem.

Answer (score 6):

This statement

```
  if(a>b)
```

involves operation (comparison) between a signed and an unsigned integer, and as per the promotion rules, the signed integer will be promoted to unsigned integer and produce a huge unsigned  value: for example, in an environment with 32-bit integer, the value would be 4294967196 (2<sup>32</sup> - 100).

Thereby, the condition will look like

```
if (100 > 4294967196)
```

and will evaluate to false, making sure the code in the `else` block is executed.

Comment: Might not be 4294967196

Comment: @Bathsheba Right, I was assuming 4-byte int, I'll add that.

Comment: You're a good egg!